# Is withParameters still supported in Breeze entity query?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I tried to use `withParameters` method on query like that:

```
query.withParameters({ includeLocation: true })
```

Unfortunately my parameter was not added to url. I use breeze.debug.js and I've found this line in it

```
//queryOptions = __extend(queryOptions, this.parameters);
```

Is that a bug ? Is `withParameters` support taken out ? Or do I do something wrong ?

I use oData

Comment: The `.withParameters` method returns a new query with the parameters added.  So make sure you assign the result:
`query = query.withParameters({ includeLocation: true });`

Comment: @SteveSchmitt - yes I'm doing that. Actually I chain all options that use on query.

Comment: @PWKad I'm using latest [1.4.8]

Comment: when I uncomment mentioned line it works.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, I have the same problem. I'm using 1.4.16, however I don't see commented line you mentioned. Which version of breeze did you use?

Comment: Hi. It's been a while - I don't remember which version was it. I guess line was removed as part of code clearence - it was commented out anyway.I guess you could look at older version from about a time this question was created and try to find this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `.withParameters` is used, the parameters are added to the URL by the data service adapter, not by the Breeze core.  That's why that line is commented out.   This allows the parameters to be encoded differently, depending upon the backend that is used.

That's great, but the data service adapter for OData that ships with Breeze 1.4.8 does not handle `.withParameters`.  The WebApi adapter does, but not the OData adapter.  We'll make sure it's added in a future release.  In the meantime, you can continue to use your workaround.

This oversight/omission is partly because we don't know any OData services that handle custom parameters.  If I may ask, what OData service are you using?

Comment: I use WCF Data Services with custom metadata providers. So I was able to add custom parameters to queries.

Comment: You should add that info to the api documentations, I was searching for this behavior long time, like "but the docs say thats the correct behavior" and then you read that it's added via data service adapter :-/ and odata doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will hopefully be fixed soon: https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/19.

In the meantime, you can use this code as a workaround (kudos to the author of this [pull request](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/pull/87)):

```
var odataAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('uriBuilder', 'OData');
var origBuildUri = odataAdapter.buildUri;
odataAdapter.buildUri = function (entityQuery, metadataStore) {
    var uri = origBuildUri(entityQuery, metadataStore);

    //Add custom query option support to webapi odata.
    //See https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/19
    if (entityQuery.parameters !== null && typeof entityQuery.parameters === 'object'
        && Object.keys(entityQuery.parameters).length)
    {
        var queryParams = {};
        for (var param in entityQuery.parameters) {
            if (/^([^\$].*)$/.test(param)) {
                var val = entityQuery.parameters[param];
                if (typeof val == 'string') val = "'" + val + "'";
                queryParams[param] = val;
            }
        }

        //get the uri without the resourceName
        var resourceName = entityQuery.resourceName;
        uri = uri.substr(resourceName.length + 1);

        //build the new uri
        uri = resourceName + toQueryOptionsString(queryParams) + '&' + uri;
    }

    //Copied from breeze.js OData adapter
    function toQueryOptionsString(queryOptions) {
        var qoStrings = [];
        for (var qoName in queryOptions) {
            var qoValue = queryOptions[qoName];
            if (qoValue !== undefined) {
                if (qoValue instanceof Array) {
                    qoValue.forEach(function (qov) {
                        qoStrings.push(qoName + "=" + encodeURIComponent(qov));
                    });
                } else {
                    qoStrings.push(qoName + "=" + encodeURIComponent(qoValue));
                }
            }
        }

        if (qoStrings.length > 0) {
            return "?" + qoStrings.join("&");
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    return uri;
};
```